# AWS/RDS rejecting file import from pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds

I'm using pgAdmin to connect to my RDS instance, which has an ssh tunnel through a vpc. That element is mostly fine; I can connect, and query the tables, and create tables. The issue is the I can not import CSVs into the newly created tables; the import wizard is rejected with 'exit code 2' (connection rejected).

I've tried opening a new port specifically to Postgres traffic, but no dice. this seems like it should be fairly basic; I can do it in my RDS instance that doesn't have SSH no problem (succeeded with the same file, same terminal, etc). It really seems like a basic item but I can't seem to even find a guide.

EDIT/Addition: I've made some progress. if I run a command like so:

```
ssh -N -L 1234:<rds-endpoint>:5432 ec2-user@<ec2-public-ip-addres> -i /Users/user/.ssh/permissionsfile.pem
```

and then in pgadmin run as a normal connection to:

```
host: localhost 
port: 1234 
username: rds-username
maintenancedatabasae: rds-database
password: rds-usernames-password
```

this works. I'm mostly just baffled that I can't figure out how to put that same ssh info into pgadmin. typically it's a super simple copy and paste operation.

Comment: hi, interesting, this might be of interest https://medium.com/@deepspaceprog/how-to-connect-via-ssh-to-an-amazon-rds-instance-running-postgresql-5e7661cdd37e

Comment: ah yes, I used that in my initial set up, and I have got it to function in command line, which makes pgAdmin's rejection all that more confusing. I *could not* get that same path to work in pgAdmin (e.g. by posting in localhost/etc). which is annoying, as I *can* ssh in via pgAdmin, just not to the next step. I'm sure I've just not pasted the right thing in the right box...

Comment: Can you add which value you entered to which setting in the connection dialog?

Comment: Basic question I know but does your user have append / write permission on the destination table? Check by looking at the target table -> properties -> security. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE

Comment: @rfkortekaas I've tried all kinds of things: using user ec2-user@ipaddress with the 1234:endpoint:5432 as the host, just ec2-user and 1234:endpoint:5432 as ssh host, etc

Comment: @sgoley, it's a fair question, and I should have included that: when I ssh from command line from this computer, I can write to the table, etc. (which makes sense, I made it on this computer from the same configuration). in short, that's not it

Answer (score 1):

First, if RDS is located in `private subnet`, pgAdmin cannot connect to RDS even if the `private subnet` is connected to `NAT Gatway` which is in `public subnet`. So to make the private subnet public, set `Internet Gateway` to the `private subnet` instead of `NAT Gatway`.

Second, check the security group's `inbound rule` of `5432(RDS postgresql port)` is open to `your computer` which has `pgAdmin`.

Third, check `Public access` of RDS setting is `Yes` showing below. If it's `No`, tools outside your VPC cannot connect to RDS.

[image]

Tell me you could successfully connect to RDS with pgAdmin or not with `3 solutions` above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and I apparently didn't write my explainer clearly enough. I can connect just fine. I can create tables in pgAdmin, and  even write tables from my machine. the only problem is I can't write to table via pgAdmin.

Comment: I only know how to connect pgAdmin to RDS. I have no idea about importing a csv file to RDS. Connecting pgAdmin to RDS has no problem so the problem should be importing csv.file part. I don't know if these youtube videos are helpful or not to import a csv file to RDS with pgAdmin. https://youtu.be/DMl5fsc8PSk or https://youtu.be/MpskUx3H1oU